# Change cell background color based on cell's text in excel using C# EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, epplus, epplus-4

I am trying to change cell's background color based on its text content. Eg: for text = "In progress" it should be Yellow, for text ="Completed" it should be Green. Not getting any clue to proceed with automation using C#.

Referred the below links but no luck

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39484426/set-conditional-background-color-of-cell-based-on-text-using-epplus-in-c-net
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52737955/epplus-conditional-formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39484426/set-conditional-background-color-of-cell-based-on-text-using-epplus-in-c-net%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52737955/epplus-conditional-formatting)

```
ExcelAddress _formatRangeAddress = new ExcelAddress("C2:C5");

var conditionalFormattingRule01 = workSheet.ConditionalFormatting.AddExpression(_formatRangeAddress);
conditionalFormattingRule01.Formula = "($C3=In Progress)";
conditionalFormattingRule01.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
conditionalFormattingRule01.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Color = Color.Yellow;
```

Color should be changed to Yellow for In progress text in the cell

Comment: The formula is the same whether you use EPPlus or Excel. Would `($C3=In Progress)` be valid in Excel? I suspect no, `In Progress` isn't quoted. You can use Excel to test the formula. You can also create a sheet in Excel that works the way you want and then *inspect it* to see how it works, either with Epplus itself or another tool. You could also use that sheet as a template instead of adding the formulas in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a couple of different ways of achieving it.

With a formula expression, you need to use the format `C2="In Progress"`, where `C2` is the top cell in the range in which the conditional formatting applies - it will still apply to other cells in the range in the right way.

```
var formatExpressionInProgress = worksheet.ConditionalFormatting.AddExpression(new ExcelAddress("C2:C5"));
formatExpressionInProgress.Formula = "C2=\"In Progress\"";
formatExpressionInProgress.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
formatExpressionInProgress.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Color = Color.Yellow;
```

More intuitively you could use the Equal type expression instead by using `.AddEqual` instead of `AddExpression`, then you just have `"Completed"` in the formula to match where the condition should apply.

```
var formatExpressionCompleted = worksheet.ConditionalFormatting.AddEqual(new ExcelAddress("C2:C5"));
formatExpressionCompleted.Formula = "\"Completed\"";
formatExpressionCompleted.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
formatExpressionCompleted.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Color = Color.Green;
```